# Is a product of $p$-subgroups still a $p$-subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

A $p$-group is a group in which every element has order a power of $p$.

Let $G$ be a group, and let $P$ and $Q$ be $p$-subgroups of $G$. Suppose that the product $PQ$ is a subgroup of $G$ (equivalently, $PQ=QP$). Is $PQ$ necessarily a $p$-subgroup of $G$?

If $P$ and $Q$ are finite then the answer is yes, because $\lvert PQ\rvert=\lvert P\rvert\cdot\lvert Q\rvert/\lvert P\cap Q\rvert$ is a power of $p$.

If $P\leq N_G(Q)$ (or vice versa), then the answer is yes.

*Proof*: Let $a\in P$ and $b\in Q$.
If $a^{p^k}=1$, then
\begin{align*}
(ab)^{p^k}&=a^{p^k}(a^{-(p^k-1)}ba^{p^k-1})(a^{-(p^k-2)}ba^{p^k-2})\cdots(a^{-2}ba^2)(a^{-1}ba)b\\
&=(a^{-(p^k-1)}ba^{p^k-1})(a^{-(p^k-2)}ba^{p^k-2})\cdots(a^{-2}ba^2)(a^{-1}ba)b\in B,
\end{align*}
so $(ab)^{p^k}$ has order a power of $p$, which shows that $ab$ has order a power of $p$.

*Alternative Proof* (thanks to David Craven): Note that $Q\trianglelefteq PQ$, where the quotient group $PQ/Q\cong P/(P\cap Q)$ is a $p$-group. Let $g\in PQ$.
Then $gQ\in PQ/Q$, so $Q=(gQ)^{p^k}=g^{p^k}Q$ for some $k$.
Then $g^{p^k}\in Q$, so $1=(g^{p^k})^{p^j}=g^{p^{k+j}}$ for some $j$.

Comment: For your proof, it's notationally simpler to note that $PQ$ is a group with $Q$ a normal subgroup. Then if $g\in PQ$, then $Qg\in P/Q$ a $p$-group, so $(Qg)^{p^n}=Q$ for some $n$. Then $g^{p^n}$ has $p$-power order, and done. This is the same proof as yours, of course.

Comment: About your question, my general position on such things is that if it isn't obviously true it's probably false... Groups can be pretty pathological.

Comment: Thanks for the cleaner proof. And your guess is my position too.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I can give you an infinite group  $G=PQ$, with $P$ and $Q$ $p$-groups but $G$ not a $p$-group, if you can give me a family of finite $p$-groups and subgroups $G_i=P_iQ_i$ where the exponents of $P_i$, $Q_i$ are bounded but those of  $G_i$ are not. But maybe there’s a reason that’s not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that this is Question 1.36 in the [Kourovka Notebook](https://kourovka-notebook.org/) (the first issue, in 1965), and the item about it in the "Archive of Solved Problems" says that it was shown that the answer is negative in general (i.e., $PQ$ need not be a $p$-group) in:

*Sysak, Ya. P.*, Products of infinite groups, Math. Inst. Akad. Nauk
Ukrain. SSR, Kiev, 1982 (Russian).

However, I've not been able to access a copy of this paper, and probably wouldn't be able to read it if I did.

Comment: The survey article "Factorizations of groups and related topics" (Amberg & Kazarin) cites the paper of Sysak, mentioning results on "triply factorized groups" constructed from "radical rings".

Comment: I contacted Sysak, and he sent me a copy of the paper "Some Examples of Factorized Groups and their Relation to Ring Theory", which is in English, and also contains a construction of counterexample.

Comment: @ThomasBrowning That paper also seems to be [available online](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110810387-026). My university seems to have a suitable institutional subscription, but it's probably not available for free without that.